# Position fixed relative to a block, not to the viewport

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have the .gridster-item (block absolutely positioned, with width and height fixed and with a overflow auto), inside i want the red block(absolutely positioned in the bottom right) to stay in where he is at the start, but when i use the scroll the red block follows the scroll.

```css
.gridster-item {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(204, 214, 249);
}

.resizer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gridster-item">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="resizer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a *wrapper* with the `position: relative` so that the *absolutely positioned* element will be positioned *relative* to it and not be affected by the *scrolling* div:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* or "inline-flex" which also only takes the content's width */
  position: relative;
}

.gridster-item {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  /*position: relative;*/
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(204, 214, 249);
}

.resizer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 17px; /* 17px because that's a typical width of the scrollbar */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="gridster-item">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsun dolor amet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="resizer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```